# Python tk select serial port from combo

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm trying to select a comport using python tk and a combo box, I found some examples of creating the pulldown which display the port and name but cannot see how to get just the device eg COM1 so I can open the port, this is what I am using but port gets set to the full name with description rather than just the device, how do I get just the device part?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import serial.tools.list_ports
import serial

def serial_ports():    
    return serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

def on_select(event=None):

    print("event.widget:", event.widget.get())
    port = event.widget.get()
    try:
        ser = serial.Serial(port, 115200, timeout=None)
    except serial.SerialException:
        print('Error Opening Port')
        exit(0)        

root = tk.Tk()

cb = ttk.Combobox(root, values=serial_ports())
cb.pack()

cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_select)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read up on [The Tkinter OptionMenu Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm). [Edit] your question and show the output of `def serial_ports():`

Comment: I know how to do it with OptionMenu, I wanted to do it with a combobox on the form, is that not possible?

Comment: ***I wanted to do it with a combobox***: The relevant part, is the same. What about my requested output?